How to handle page breaks to avoid splitting content across pages in a document using Google Docs API?
I'm working on a document where I need to ensure that content doesn't get split between two pages. If there's enough space on the current page, the content should be written there. Otherwise, it should start on the next page to keep it intact.
For example, if I have a section of text or data, I want to avoid scenarios where half of it is on one page and the other half is on the next.
Google Docs API
Java with spring boot
How can I achieve this behavior programmatically
